# CUDA streams and concurrent kernel execution

Tags: concurrency, cuda, cuda-streams

I would like to use streams in order to parallelize the execution of kernels that work on separate device data arrays. Data were allocated on the device and filled from previous kernels.

I have written the following program that shows I can't reach my goal so far. Indeed, the kernels on two non-default streams execute sequentially in their respective streams.

The same behaviour is observed on 2 Intel machines with latest Debian linux version. One has a Tesla C2075 with CUDA 4.2 and the other has a Geforce 460GT with CUDA 5.0. The Visual Profiler shows sequential execution in both the 4.2 and also 5.0 CUDA version.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>

#include <curand.h>

using namespace std;

// compile and run this way:
// nvcc cuStreamsBasics.cu  -arch=sm_20  -o testCuStream   -lcuda -lcufft -lcurand 
// testCuStream  1024 512 512


/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
//  "useful" macros
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */


#define MSG_ASSERT( CONDITION, MSG )                    \
  if (! (CONDITION))                            \
    {                                   \
    std::cerr << std::endl << "Dynamic assertion `" #CONDITION "` failed in " << __FILE__ \
          << " line " << __LINE__ << ": <" << MSG << ">" << std::endl;  \
    exit( 1 );                              \
    } \ 



#define ASSERT( CONDITION ) \
  MSG_ASSERT( CONDITION, " " )



// allocate data on the GPU memory, unpinned
#define CUDALLOC_GPU( _TAB, _DIM, _DATATYPE ) \
  MSG_ASSERT( \
  cudaMalloc( (void**) &_TAB, _DIM * sizeof( _DATATYPE) ) \ 
== cudaSuccess , "failed CUDALLOC" );



/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
// the CUDA kernels
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */


// finds index in 1D array from sequential blocks
#define CUDAINDEX_1D                \
  blockIdx.y * ( gridDim.x * blockDim.x ) + \
  blockIdx.x * blockDim.x +         \
  threadIdx.x;                  \



__global__ void 
kernel_diva(float* data, float value, int array_size)
{
  int i = CUDAINDEX_1D
    if (i < array_size) 
      data[i] /= value;
}


__global__ void 
kernel_jokea(float* data, float value, int array_size)
{
  int i = CUDAINDEX_1D
    if (i < array_size) 
      data[i] *= value + sin( double(i)) * 1/ cos( double(i) );
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
// usage
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */


static void
usage(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  if ((argc -1) != 3)
    {

      printf("Usage: %s <dimx> <dimy> <dimz> \n", argv[0]);
      printf("do stuff\n");

      exit(1);
    }  
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
// main program, finally!
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */


int 
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  usage(argc, argv);
  size_t x_dim = atoi( argv[1] );
  size_t y_dim = atoi( argv[2] );
  size_t z_dim = atoi( argv[3] );



  cudaStream_t stream1, stream2;
  ASSERT( cudaStreamCreate( &stream1 ) == cudaSuccess ); 
  ASSERT( cudaStreamCreate( &stream2 ) == cudaSuccess ); 



  size_t size = x_dim * y_dim * z_dim;
  float *data1, *data2;
  CUDALLOC_GPU( data1, size, float);
  CUDALLOC_GPU( data2, size, float);


  curandGenerator_t gen;
  curandCreateGenerator(&gen, CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT);
  /* Set seed */
  curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(gen, 1234ULL);
  /* Generate n floats on device */
  curandGenerateUniform(gen, data1, size);
  curandGenerateUniform(gen, data2, size);


  dim3 dimBlock( z_dim, 1, 1);
  dim3 dimGrid( x_dim, y_dim, 1);

  clock_t start;
  double diff;


  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  start = clock(); 
  kernel_diva <<< dimGrid, dimBlock>>>( data1, 5.55f, size);   
  kernel_jokea<<< dimGrid, dimBlock>>>( data1, 5.55f, size);   
  kernel_diva <<< dimGrid, dimBlock>>>( data2, 5.55f, size); 
  kernel_jokea<<< dimGrid, dimBlock>>>( data2, 5.55f, size); 
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  diff = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

  cout << endl << "sequential: " << diff;


  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  start = clock(); 
  kernel_diva <<< dimGrid, dimBlock, 0, stream1 >>>( data1, 5.55f, size); 
  kernel_diva <<< dimGrid, dimBlock, 0, stream2 >>>( data2, 5.55f, size); 
  kernel_jokea<<< dimGrid, dimBlock, 0, stream1 >>>( data1, 5.55f, size); 
  kernel_jokea<<< dimGrid, dimBlock, 0, stream2 >>>( data2, 5.55f, size); 
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  diff = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

  cout << endl << "parallel: " << diff;



  cudaStreamDestroy( stream1 ); 
  cudaStreamDestroy( stream2 ); 


  return 0;
}
```

Typically, the dimension of the arrays is `512^3` single `float`. I usually just cut the array in blocks of `(512,1,1)` threads that I put on a grid of size `(1<<15, (rest), 1)`.

Thank you in advance for any hint or comment.

Best regards.

Comment: The current code sample launches > 2^19 warps. kernel_diva and kernel_jokea perform very little processing. Compute capability < 3.5 devices will dispatch all work from the first kernel before dispatching work from the second. Due to the short processing time you may not see any overlap. If you reduce the gridDim to (1,1,1) and increase the work per thread by 1000x (just do a for loop) do you see overlap between the two kernels? Your kernel performance will likely improve greatly if have each thread process multiple data elements reducing launch and index calculation overhead.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So far, I assumed a thread should get busy with only one array slot. I've recently found a few notes that break this assumption, including http://llpanorama.wordpress.com/2008/06/11/threads-and-blocks-and-grids-oh-my/ . I will have a close look at it and come back here when I'll have significant results. Thank you again!

Comment: The wordpress article contains a number of items that not accurate. If you want a lower level understanding of the GPU I would recommend you watch the GTC 2013 talk Performance Optimization: Programming Guidelines and GPU Architecture Details Behind them [vid](http://nvidia.fullviewmedia.com/gtc2013/0321-210H-S3466.html) [pdf](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/presentations/S3466-Programming-Guidelines-GPU-Architecture.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

I'm trying to provide an interpretation to why you do not see execution overlap of your two kernels. To this end, I have constructed the code reported below, which uses your two kernels and monitors which Streaming Multiprocessor (SM) each block runs on. I'm using CUDA 6.5 (Release Candidate) and I'm running on a GT540M card, which has only `2` SMs, so it provides a simple playground to work with. The `blockSize` choice is delegated to the new CUDA 6.5 `cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize` facility.

**THE CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

//#define DEBUG_MODE

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

/**************************************************/
/* STREAMING MULTIPROCESSOR IDENTIFICATION NUMBER */
/**************************************************/
__device__ unsigned int get_smid(void) {
    unsigned int ret;
    asm("mov.u32 %0, %smid;" : "=r"(ret) );
    return ret;
}

/************/
/* KERNEL 1 */
/************/
__global__ void kernel_1(float * __restrict__ data, const float value, int *sm, int N)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (i < N) {
        data[i] = data[i] / value;
        if (threadIdx.x==0) sm[blockIdx.x]=get_smid();
    }

}

//__global__ void kernel_1(float* data, float value, int N)
//{
//    int start = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
//    for (int i = start; i < N; i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x)
//    {
//        data[i] = data[i] / value; 
//    }
//}

/************/
/* KERNEL 2 */
/************/
__global__ void  kernel_2(float * __restrict__ data, const float value, int *sm, int N)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;

    if (i < N) {
        data[i] = data[i] * (value + sin(double(i)) * 1./cos(double(i)));
        if (threadIdx.x==0) sm[blockIdx.x]=get_smid();
    }
}

//__global__ void  kernel_2(float* data, float value, int N)
//{
//    int start = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
//    for (int i = start; i < N; i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x)
//    {
//        data[i] = data[i] * (value + sin(double(i)) * 1./cos(double(i)));
//    }
//}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    const int N = 10000;

    const float value = 5.55f;

    const int rep_num = 20;

    // --- CPU memory allocations
    float *h_data1 = (float*) malloc(N*sizeof(float));
    float *h_data2 = (float*) malloc(N*sizeof(float));
    float *h_data1_ref = (float*) malloc(N*sizeof(float));
    float *h_data2_ref = (float*) malloc(N*sizeof(float));

    // --- CPU data initializations
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        h_data1[i] = rand() / RAND_MAX;
        h_data2[i] = rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }

    // --- GPU memory allocations
    float *d_data1, *d_data2;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_data1, N*sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_data2, N*sizeof(float)));

    // --- CPU -> GPU memory transfers
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_data1, h_data1, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_data2, h_data2, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- CPU data initializations
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        h_data1_ref[i] = h_data1[i] / value;
        h_data2_ref[i] = h_data2[i] * (value + sin(double(i)) * 1./cos(double(i)));
    }

    // --- Stream creations
    cudaStream_t stream1, stream2;
    gpuErrchk(cudaStreamCreate(&stream1)); 
    gpuErrchk(cudaStreamCreate(&stream2)); 

    // --- Launch parameters configuration
    int blockSize1, blockSize2, minGridSize1, minGridSize2, gridSize1, gridSize2;
    cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize(&minGridSize1, &blockSize1, kernel_1, 0, N); 
    cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize(&minGridSize2, &blockSize2, kernel_2, 0, N); 

    gridSize1 = (N + blockSize1 - 1) / blockSize1; 
    gridSize2 = (N + blockSize2 - 1) / blockSize2; 

    // --- Allocating space for SM IDs
    int *h_sm_11 = (int*) malloc(gridSize1*sizeof(int)); 
    int *h_sm_12 = (int*) malloc(gridSize1*sizeof(int));
    int *h_sm_21 = (int*) malloc(gridSize2*sizeof(int));
    int *h_sm_22 = (int*) malloc(gridSize2*sizeof(int));
    int *d_sm_11, *d_sm_12, *d_sm_21, *d_sm_22;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_sm_11, gridSize1*sizeof(int)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_sm_12, gridSize1*sizeof(int)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_sm_21, gridSize2*sizeof(int)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_sm_22, gridSize2*sizeof(int)));

    // --- Timing individual kernels
    float time;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    for (int i=0; i<rep_num; i++) kernel_1<<<gridSize1, blockSize1>>>(d_data1, value, d_sm_11, N);   

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("Kernel 1 - elapsed time:  %3.3f ms \n", time/rep_num);

    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    for (int i=0; i<rep_num; i++) kernel_2<<<gridSize2, blockSize2>>>(d_data1, value, d_sm_21, N);   

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("Kernel 2 - elapsed time:  %3.3f ms \n", time/rep_num);

    // --- No stream case
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    kernel_1<<<gridSize1, blockSize1>>>(d_data1, value, d_sm_11, N);   
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize()); 
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_data1, d_data1, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    // --- Results check
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        if (h_data1[i] != h_data1_ref[i]) {
            printf("Kernel1 - Error at i = %i; Host = %f; Device = %f\n", i, h_data1_ref[i], h_data1[i]);
            return;
        }
    }
#endif
    kernel_2<<<gridSize2, blockSize2>>>(d_data1, value, d_sm_21, N);   
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize()); 
#endif
    kernel_1<<<gridSize1, blockSize1>>>(d_data2, value, d_sm_12, N); 
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize()); 
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_data2, h_data2, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
#endif
    kernel_2<<<gridSize2, blockSize2>>>(d_data2, value, d_sm_22, N); 
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize()); 
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_data2, d_data2, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        if (h_data2[i] != h_data2_ref[i]) {
            printf("Kernel2 - Error at i = %i; Host = %f; Device = %f\n", i, h_data2_ref[i], h_data2[i]);
            return;
        }
    }
#endif

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("No stream - elapsed time:  %3.3f ms \n", time);

    // --- Stream case
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    kernel_1<<<gridSize1, blockSize1, 0, stream1 >>>(d_data1, value, d_sm_11, N); 
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize()); 
#endif
    kernel_1<<<gridSize1, blockSize1, 0, stream2 >>>(d_data2, value, d_sm_12, N); 
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize()); 
#endif
    kernel_2<<<gridSize2, blockSize2, 0, stream1 >>>(d_data1, value, d_sm_21, N); 
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize()); 
#endif
    kernel_2<<<gridSize2, blockSize2, 0, stream2 >>>(d_data2, value, d_sm_22, N); 
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize()); 
#endif

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("Stream - elapsed time:  %3.3f ms \n", time);

    cudaStreamDestroy(stream1); 
    cudaStreamDestroy(stream2); 

    printf("Test passed!\n");

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_sm_11, d_sm_11, gridSize1*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_sm_12, d_sm_12, gridSize1*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_sm_21, d_sm_21, gridSize2*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_sm_22, d_sm_22, gridSize2*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    printf("Kernel 1: gridSize = %i; blockSize = %i\n", gridSize1, blockSize1);
    printf("Kernel 2: gridSize = %i; blockSize = %i\n", gridSize2, blockSize2);
    for (int i=0; i<gridSize1; i++) {
        printf("Kernel 1 - Data 1: blockNumber = %i; SMID = %d\n", i, h_sm_11[i]);
        printf("Kernel 1 - Data 2: blockNumber = %i; SMID = %d\n", i, h_sm_12[i]);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<gridSize2; i++) {
        printf("Kernel 2 - Data 1: blockNumber = %i; SMID = %d\n", i, h_sm_21[i]);
        printf("Kernel 2 - Data 2: blockNumber = %i; SMID = %d\n", i, h_sm_22[i]);
    }
    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```

**KERNEL TIMINGS FOR `N = 100` and `N = 10000`**

```
N = 100
kernel_1    0.003ms
kernel_2    0.005ms    

N = 10000
kernel_1    0.011ms
kernel_2    0.053ms
```

So, kernel 1 is more computationally expensive than kernel 2.

**RESULTS FOR `N = 100`**

```
Kernel 1: gridSize = 1; blockSize = 100
Kernel 2: gridSize = 1; blockSize = 100
Kernel 1 - Data 1: blockNumber = 0; SMID = 0
Kernel 1 - Data 2: blockNumber = 0; SMID = 1
Kernel 2 - Data 1: blockNumber = 0; SMID = 0
Kernel 2 - Data 2: blockNumber = 0; SMID = 1
```

In this case, each kernel is launched with only one block and this is the timeline.

[image]

As you can see, the overlap occurs. By looking at the above outcomes, the scheduler delivers the single blocks of the two calls to kernel 1 in parallel to the two available SMs and then does the same for kernel 2. This seems to be the main reason why overlap occurs.

**RESULTS FOR `N = 10000`**

```
Kernel 1: gridSize = 14; blockSize = 768
Kernel 2: gridSize = 10; blockSize = 1024
Kernel 1 - Data 1: blockNumber = 0; SMID = 0
Kernel 1 - Data 2: blockNumber = 0; SMID = 1
Kernel 1 - Data 1: blockNumber = 1; SMID = 1
Kernel 1 - Data 2: blockNumber = 1; SMID = 0
Kernel 1 - Data 1: blockNumber = 2; SMID = 0
Kernel 1 - Data 2: blockNumber = 2; SMID = 1
Kernel 1 - Data 1: blockNumber = 3; SMID = 1
Kernel 1 - Data 2: blockNumber = 3; SMID = 0
Kernel 1 - Data 1: blockNumber = 4; SMID = 0
Kernel 1 - Data 2: blockNumber = 4; SMID = 1
Kernel 1 - Data 1: blockNumber = 5; SMID = 1
Kernel 1 - Data 2: blockNumber = 5; SMID = 0
Kernel 1 - Data 1: blockNumber = 6; SMID = 0
Kernel 1 - Data 2: blockNumber = 6; SMID = 0
Kernel 1 - Data 1: blockNumber = 7; SMID = 1
Kernel 1 - Data 2: blockNumber = 7; SMID = 1
Kernel 1 - Data 1: blockNumber = 8; SMID = 0
Kernel 1 - Data 2: blockNumber = 8; SMID = 1
Kernel 1 - Data 1: blockNumber = 9; SMID = 1
Kernel 1 - Data 2: blockNumber = 9; SMID = 0
Kernel 1 - Data 1: blockNumber = 10; SMID = 0
Kernel 1 - Data 2: blockNumber = 10; SMID = 0
Kernel 1 - Data 1: blockNumber = 11; SMID = 1
Kernel 1 - Data 2: blockNumber = 11; SMID = 1
Kernel 1 - Data 1: blockNumber = 12; SMID = 0
Kernel 1 - Data 2: blockNumber = 12; SMID = 1
Kernel 1 - Data 1: blockNumber = 13; SMID = 1
Kernel 1 - Data 2: blockNumber = 13; SMID = 0
Kernel 2 - Data 1: blockNumber = 0; SMID = 0
Kernel 2 - Data 2: blockNumber = 0; SMID = 0
Kernel 2 - Data 1: blockNumber = 1; SMID = 1
Kernel 2 - Data 2: blockNumber = 1; SMID = 1
Kernel 2 - Data 1: blockNumber = 2; SMID = 1
Kernel 2 - Data 2: blockNumber = 2; SMID = 0
Kernel 2 - Data 1: blockNumber = 3; SMID = 0
Kernel 2 - Data 2: blockNumber = 3; SMID = 1
Kernel 2 - Data 1: blockNumber = 4; SMID = 1
Kernel 2 - Data 2: blockNumber = 4; SMID = 0
Kernel 2 - Data 1: blockNumber = 5; SMID = 0
Kernel 2 - Data 2: blockNumber = 5; SMID = 1
Kernel 2 - Data 1: blockNumber = 6; SMID = 1
Kernel 2 - Data 2: blockNumber = 6; SMID = 0
Kernel 2 - Data 1: blockNumber = 7; SMID = 0
Kernel 2 - Data 2: blockNumber = 7; SMID = 1
Kernel 2 - Data 1: blockNumber = 8; SMID = 1
Kernel 2 - Data 2: blockNumber = 8; SMID = 0
Kernel 2 - Data 1: blockNumber = 9; SMID = 0
Kernel 2 - Data 2: blockNumber = 9; SMID = 1
```

This is the timeline:

[image]

In this case, no overlap occurs. According to the above outcomes, this does not mean that the two SMs are not simultaneously exploited, but (I think) that, due to the larger number of blocks to be launched, assigning two blocks of different kernels or the two blocks of the same kernel does not make much difference in terms of performance and thus the scheduler chooses the second option.

I have tested that, considering more work done per thread, the behavior keeps the same.